# With PayPal REST SDK, how I can I get the buyer's country but not the entire address?

Tags: privacy, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm using the PayPal REST SDK for payments, but since I'm selling digital goods, I don't need a shipping address, so for privacy reasons **I don't want one**.

However, it sounds like I need the billing **country** for Euro VAT purposes, and I don't know how to do that.

I've configured a *payment experience* using the following request:

```
{
    "flow_config": {
        "landing_page_type": "Billing"
    },
    "input_fields": {
        "allow_note": false,
        "no_shipping": 1
    },
    "name": "my name"
}
```

The `no_shipping` parameter is documented thus:

> Determines whether or not PayPal displays shipping address fields on
>   the experience pages. Allowed values: 0, 1, or 2. When set to 0,
>   PayPal displays the shipping address on the PayPal pages. When set to
>   1, PayPal does not display shipping address fields whatsoever. When
>   set to 2, if you do not pass the shipping address, PayPal obtains it
>   from the buyer’s account profile. For digital goods, this field is
>   required, and you must set it to 1.

And preparing the payment:

```
{
    "experience_profile_id": "XP-JVB9-FJ5Y-RMWS-ZCTS",
    "intent": "sale",
    "payer": {
        "payment_method": "paypal"
    },
    etc…
}
```

Executing the payment returns:

```
{
    "create_time": "2015-02-05T08:24:53Z",
    "id": "PAY-snip",
    "intent": "sale",
    "links": [
        {
            "href": "snip",
            "method": "GET",
            "rel": "self"
        }
    ],
    "payer": {
        "payer_info": {
            "email": "test@test.com",
            "first_name": "Test",
            "last_name": "Buyer",
            "payer_id": "snip"
        },
        "payment_method": "paypal"
    },
    etc…
}
```

Which is great: no address… but also no country code.

I think PayPal is missing another value, which requests the country code but not the rest of the address…

Comment: I'm having the same issue you had here... Did you finally came up with any solution?

Comment: No real solution unless PayPal improves their API. For now, I've chosen to not store the country code. Or you can request the full address info and just only store the country code.

Comment: Beware that the 2013 ammendment ( http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2013:284:0001:0009:EN:PDF ) requires you to have 2 non-exclusive proofs of the customer's country. Even if PayPal provided you with country, you still need to have another piece of proof such as IP address, bank details, phone number or "other commercially relevant information"  (see Article 24f).